# Cómo "extraer" los datos que devuelve http.post en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, web, spring

Quiero saber cómo guardar el idPlaylist (que me devuelve `http.post`) en una variable para después usarlo en el `http.put`

```
crearPlaylist(playlist : Playlist){

    var UrlLog = "https://censoredherokuapp.com/playlist/save/";
    var UrlLog2 = "http://censored.herokuapp.com/cliente/createPlaylist";
    var myString = JSON.stringify(playlist);
    var idPlaylist;

    var response = this.http.post(UrlLog,myString,httpOptions).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      idPlaylist = data["id"];
      return idPlaylist;
    });

    console.log(idPlaylist);
    this.http.put(UrlLog2+this.usserLogged.correo+idPlaylist,httpOptions);


    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura estaba bien, simplemente había que cambiar el "idPlaylist" del put y poner  en su lugar `this.http.put(UrlLog2+this.usserLogged.correo+response,httpOptions);`
 porque el idPlaylist se está asignando a `var response`cuando hace `return idPlaylist`